# Python "for in" loop running only once

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import sys

csv_file = csv.reader(open('sample_1.csv', "rb"), delimiter=';')
csv_file_sounds = csv.reader(open('sample_2.csv', "rb"), delimiter=';')

for row in csv_file:
        for row2 in csv_file_sounds:
                if row2[21] == row[0]:
                        print row2[15]
```

And the "for row in csv_file" loop running only once, but I have lot of lines in `sample_1.csv`. What I missed? I want to find `sample_1.csv`'s strings in `sample_2.csv`

(English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part.)

Comment: `csv_file_sounds = list(csv.reader(open('sample_2.csv', "rb"), delimiter=';'))` you're done. `csv_file_sounds` is an iterator. It runs only once by design.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You have right, its working fine, thank you, I'am thankful. Can you post ur comment as an answer?

Comment: Your inner loop reads the entire `sample_2` file.  Since you never reset that file handle, the second iteration of `row in csv_file` compares to an empty `row2` set of choices.

Comment: @G3ph4z it's a classic with iterators, follow the duplicate link for another answer (also by me :)) BTW use a `set` or a `dict` to get rid of that second loop (the other answer explains that much, in a different context but it's the exact same issue)